# Training computationally cheap models for feature selection and then extending to more flexible models

Tags: feature-selection, data-preprocessing

To what extent can I apply lessons learnt about the model performance on a simple "cheap" model (e.g. Naive Bayes, LDA) to a more flexible model (i.e. ensemble of trees, neural networks)?

For example:

> How irresponsible is it to evaluate preprocessing strategies (e.g.
> should I use Fourier transform? PCA? Which signal segment length?
> Which robust standardization method? Which hyper-parameters etc.) using a simple, cheap model
> and then assume the same principles will also hold for flexible
> models?

- On the one hand this seems like a practical solution where you could
  rapidly prototype in a computationally cheap way. The "information"
  the data contains after preprocessing would, after all, be the same for a simple
  and a more sophisticated model?
- On the other hand, I can recognize that a more flexible/expensive model might be able to transform the input data in a more intricate way. As a result, you might make a mistake in assuming that the optimal pre-processing procedure for the
  simple model is also near-optimal for the expensive model.